# Objects are not valid as react Child with keys _h, _i, _j

Tags: react-native

```
{_forEachKey().then((keys) => {
      keys.map((key)=> {
            alert('))))' + JSON.parse(_getData(key)));
          
      }
     )})
    }
```

If this code is inside the return (..... if code is here ); it throws Objects are not valid as react Child with keys _h, _i, _j

But if I put it outside the return () but where the Class starts:

function PaymentScreen({route, navigation}) {
..here
}

it works.

What could be causing this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please try it in following way

```
{_forEachKey().then((keys) => {
 return (
         keys.map((key)=> {
         return(
                 alert(`)))) ${JSON.parse(_getData(key))}`);
        )  
    )
  
}
```

If it's will not work than please share you array list.

Comment: I have posted entire code

Answer (score 0):

```
import { CardField, useConfirmPayment, useStripe, BillingDetails, Address } from '@stripe/stripe-react-native';
import { Button, Text, View, Image, TextInput, StyleSheet} from "react-native";
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import AsyncStorage from '@react-native-async-storage/async-storage';

    _storeData = async (customerID, itemId) => {
        //alert(customerID);
        try {
            await AsyncStorage.setItem(
                customerID, 
                itemId
            );
        } catch (error) {
            alert('Err: ', error);
        }
    }

   async function _getData(customerID)  {
        try {
           // alert(customerID);
            const value = await AsyncStorage.getItem(customerID);
           // alert('V:-'+value);
            if(value !== null) {
                console.log(value);
                return value;
            }
        } catch (error) {
            alert('Err: ', error);
        }
    }

    async function _forEachKey() {
        return (await AsyncStorage.getAllKeys());
    }

   function PaymentScreen({route, navigation}) {

    const { confirmPayment, loading } = useConfirmPayment();
    const {it} = route.params;
    _storeData(it.id.value, JSON.stringify(it));

      

     return (
    <View>

  {
    AsyncStorage.getAllKeys()
    .then(async ( e ) => 
        {e}
  )}

    </View>
```

);
}